Overall probability of getting heads when flipping a coin, where every success is followed by another success?
Suppose I have have a coin that lands heads with probability X, and every time it lands heads the next flip is guaranteed to also land heads. What is the overall probability it lands heads across an infinite number of trials?
I simulated the problem with a Python script and got the following results, though I can't figure out why.



X
probability




.1
.182


.25
.400


.5
.667


.75
.857


.9
.948



Edit: to clarify, the guarantee to land heads is only for the next flip, and afterwards the probability returns to X.

Have you tried any other analytical approaches? It might be helpful to include those so others can better understand where you're stuck.

Also I'm assuming that after the second heads there is an $X$ chance of getting heads again? From your simulations it seems that the probability is $\frac{2}{(1/x) + 1} $

If it ever lands heads, then it's going to land heads forever if things are exactly as you say (and then it's easy to see that it's almost surely going to land heads infinitely often unless $X = 0$). You need to clarify your question (@Nic has very reasonably taken a different reading from me).

@Nic Equivalently, the probability is $\frac{2x}{1+x}$

In either case, the probability for the complement of never getting a head across an infinite sequence is:  $1-\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (1-X)^n$, which converges to $1$ for $0\lt X\leq 1$

@Osgboy  How are you interpreting: "lands heads across an infinite number of trials"?

If we have a coin that lands heads with a probability $x$ and we let $k = 1/x$ then, on average, for every $k$ flips (not counting any guaranteed heads) there will be $1$ head and $k-1$ tails. Then, we just have to double count each heads to get the desired answer. So we get $2$ heads for $k+1$ flips. Hence the probability is:
$$ p = \frac{2}{k+1} $$
if we want this in terms of $x$ we have:
$$ p = \frac{2}{(1/x) + 1} = \frac{2x}{1+x} $$

Ah!  That is the probability for obtaining a head after an arbitrary large number of prior trials.

Treat this as a Markov chain with three states:

$H$: the last flip was heads (though it could potentially have been tails)
$G$: the last flip was heads due to the guarantee
$T$: the last flip was not heads (i.e. tails, though this is also the starting position)

Then the transition matrix is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0  \\
x & 0 & 1-x\\
x & 0 & 1-x
\end{pmatrix}$$
You can use this to show that after $n$ throws the probabilities of being in each of the three states are $\frac{x}{1+x}\left(1-(-x)^n\right)$, $\frac{x}{1+x}\left(1-(-x)^{n-1}\right)$ and $\frac{1-x}{1+x}\left(1-(-x)^n\right)$ respectively
which tend towards $\frac{x}{1+x}$, $\frac{x}{1+x}$ and $\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ respectively as $n$ increases, i.e. in the limit with the proportion of heads $\frac{2x}{1+x}$ (as others have suggested) and the proportion of tails $\frac{1-x}{1+x}$.
